# How do I slow down a b2Body heading toward the edge of the screen incrementally to where the velocity is 0 when it reaches the edge?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I have a b2Body that is heading toward the top of the screen at an unknown "linearVelocity.y". How can I have the linearVelocity slow down and be 0 when it is just below the top and let gravity take over?

- I've tried LinearDamping, but the object doesn't always slow down enough before leaving the top of the screen.
- I've also tried to use ApplyImpulse with `-linearVelocity.y` when the `object.position >= screen.Height - object.contentSize.height`, but that doesn't seem to slow it down in a smooth enough manner.

Any help would be amazing!

Edit: An example of this could be the height limit in the game "Tiny Wings"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of applying the entire negative impulse in a single frame... detect when your body has passed a certain height, and start to slowly decrement the linear velocity by a small amount over the course of multiple frames, until the `linearVelocity` reaches 0... at that point, you can simply let gravity take over.

Comment: I guess my question now is... How much do I need to decrement it every frame since the the linearVelocity.y can be a variety of difference speeds? Thanks for the response!

Comment: You can experiment with different amounts to find out what looks right, but if I were you, I would decrement the velocity based on how fast it was going when it passed initially passed your threshold, and how far past the threshold it currently is...